# Ubuntu 12.04 Wipe

Tags: 12.04, format, permanent-delete

I would like to know how to wipe the contents of my hard drive completely?

Also, It will be able to boot new Ubuntu on this hard drive after wiping, or it will be completely broken?

Comment: Do you want to delete all of your data and personal settings?

Comment: If you want to install Ubuntu again, just choose the "use entire drive" option under installation.

Answer (score 2):

## Clearing hard drive for a fresh start

1. Launch a Linux livecd with parted or gparted (preferred) installed. This can be any Ubuntu installation disc or Linux rescue USB:
2. ### Graphical

   1. Open gparted and select the hard you wish to wipe in the top left corner. 
      [image: Step 1]
      You can see the two hard drives on my Chromebook, the 16GB internal SSD and my 64GB SD card. Ignore all the crazy partitioning on this device. ChromeOS is weird.
   2. Select "Device" on the menu strip. Click "Create Partition Table...".
      [image: Step 2]
   3. The two options here are either msdos (aka MBR) or gpt. If you plan on installing Windows on this hard drive, you must choose msdos. Otherwise, go with gpt.
      [image: Step 3]
   4. Now you can either leave the hard drive empty and allow an installer to create the partitions or you may create them now using gparted.

### With the terminal

1. First, type:

   ```
   $ sudo parted
   (parted) print all
   ```

   to view all discs and determine which hard disc is the one you wish to wipe.
2. Now type:

   ```
   $ sudo parted <disc> mktable <type>
   ```

   <disc> being something like "/dev/sda" or "/dev/sdb" (Without quotations) and <type> being either "gpt" or "msdos". Choose "msdos" if you plan on installing Windows onto this hard drive with Linux. Otherwise, choose "gpt".

Comment: Add Screenshot !!

Comment: @AshutoshKale Was 2 AM when I posted this. There up now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to just boot from the Install/Live Ubuntu CD, and format through the installer.  Then create the partitions manually with it as well... and continue to install Ubuntu.  To do this you would have to select Something Else from the screen where you are asked how you want to install ubuntu.  But Jak12132's way is very thorough so you may just want to do that.